# wordpress enqueue admin scripts on specific page

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a plugin that requires some js and css file on the admin side.

I enqueue them like this:

```
function checkin_page_files() {
    if ( is_page('/admin.php?page=reports_Systems')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'checkin-page-style', content_url() . '/plugins/reports/includes/checkin_page/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'checkin-page-js', content_url() . '/plugins/reports/assets/js/checkinPageJavascripts.js', array(), false, false );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'checkin-live-validation-js', content_url() . '/plugins/reports/assets/js/liveValidation.js', array(), false, false );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'checkin_page_files', 0 );
```

and, as you can see, I am trying to specify that I'd like to include them only if the page is `/admin.php?page=reports_Systems`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Without the if statement, the files are included properly, so it's not a path error.

How can I achieve this?
All the examples I saw online used the if statement to provide a page like `admin.php`, or `post.php`, without the `?`.

I think that the reason why mine doesn't work is because of the `?` and I wasn't able to find examples like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use get_ current_screen()->id to get the current screen id of pages where you want to enqueue your custom script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can check for the $_GET variable 'page'. Wordpress has a built in method get_query_var() to get the $_GET variable from the url.

```
if(get_query_var('page') == reports_Systems){
//enqueue your scripts
}
```