# Enqueue admin script only on Theme settings

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, conditional-statements

I tried to follow this = [wordpress enqueue admin scripts on specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318564/wordpress-enqueue-admin-scripts-on-specific-page)

how can I enqueue a script only on the theme options

i tried following:

Theme option url is : http://theme:8888/wp-admin/admin.php?page=theme_settings&tab=layout-tab

```html
function theme_admin_style() {

  if(get_query_var('page') == theme_settings ){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-grid', get_template_directory_uri().'/assests/css/bootstrap-grid.css');
  }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_admin_style');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_query_var` works on in relation to `$wp_query` and there is no query on your custom admin page, so it's better to just use `$_GET`

```
function theme_admin_style() {

  if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'theme_settings' ){
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-grid', get_template_directory_uri().'/assests/css/bootstrap-grid.css');
  }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_admin_style');
```